# Finding the error in my use of the strcat function

Tags: c, strcpy, strcat

Please help me i can't solve this question i've got in university. I asked in our university forum and they said this clue: "what is the difference if you send a long string to strcat, or you send the string B? "

Explain what is wrong with the next program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char A[10];
    char B[20];
    strcpy(A, "A student");
    strcpy(B, "fail the exam");
    printf("%s\n", strcat(A, B));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the program will output [ A student fail the exam ], can you be more clear with your question

Comment: Did you execute the program ? Did you get any error ?

Comment: Also note the missing space. Even if `A` is large enough, it would print `A studentfail the exam`.

Comment: Read: [`strcat()` implementation works but causes a core dump at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1673391/grijesh-chauhan?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=5)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Should you find an answer acceptable, consider checking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of `strcat` must be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string. So change it to :

```
char A[30];
```

or you will probably get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

See "A student fail the exam" is **large than 10**.

So at least use `char A[24]` instead of `char A[10]`

Answer (score 1):

Because `strcat(s,t)` concatenates t *to the end of* s, s must be large enough to hold the new, concatenated string. It returns a pointer to the first character in s.

Answer (score 0):

Array A should be large enough to hold the contents of array B other wise strcat behaviour is **unpredictable**, segmentation fault may occur, Application may get crash.Refer the link below. [Link]http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat